# Excel SQL concat fields to make complete date

Tags: sql, excel, concatenation

Our main system stores the date in three separate pieces. I would like to combine them so that I can use them in Excel. I can combine them in Excel easily enough, but I would like the imported data to come correctly in the first place. The data in the main system is stored as 17 for the year, 2 for the month and 22 as the date. In the select statement I would like it to come as a new field called Date1 where it looks like this: 2/22/2017 I am not sure if the data is stored as text or numeric but I think it might be as text.

[Connection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjmUp.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5t0J.png)

Comment: The answer depends on the database engine, which you failed to specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month||'/'||date||'/'||year AS date1 FROM...
```

But be aware, some databases have inbuilt date format functions to cover this...